# React Router 4.x - PrivateRoute not working after connecting to Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

PrivateRoute available in Example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow is not working after connecting with Redux.

My PrivateRoute look almost same to the original version but only **connected to Redux** and used it instead of fakeAuth in the original example.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
   {...rest}
   render={props =>
   auth.isAuthenticated
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />}
  />
);

 PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
     auth: state.auth
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**Usage and result:-**

1. NOT working but **desired & expecting** to work

   - `<PrivateRoute path="/member" component={MemberPage} />`
2. working but NOT desired to used like this

   - `<PrivateRoute path="/member" component={MemberPage} auth={auth} />`
3. working. JUST to work but NOT desired to used at all. An understanding from this point is that, if you connect original PrivateRoute to Redux you need to pass some additional props (any prop) to make PrivateRoute working otherwise it does not work. **Anyone, please give some hint on this behavior**. This is my main question

   - `<PrivateRoute path="/member" component={MemberPage} anyprop={{a:1}} />`

Answer (score 12):

Complementary to @Tharaka answer you can pass `{pure: false}` to `connect` method as described in [react-redux troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux).

*React-redux* makes shallow comparison of props in `shouldComponentUpdate` hook to avoid unnecessary re-renders. If context props changed (react-router) it doesn’t check for that and it assumes nothing has changed.

`{ pure:false }` simply disables this shallow comparison.

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: I believe this answers the question best inline with expected results. Worked for me

Comment: Please elaborate what `pure` means and what is the downside of using it. A link-based answer is only half as good as a full one ;)

Answer (score 9):

According to [react-router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration) you may just wrap your `connect` function with `withRouter`:

```
// before
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Something)

// after
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Something))
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Brilliant! This was the simplest solution. I also removed the shouldComponentUpdate() function as well which worked for me

Comment: Link is broken. It seems that [React Router v4 and 5 withRouter docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) is trying to explain but it is clear like your answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is known issue in react-redux and you can read more about this [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/507). The problem is `connect` HoC have implemented `shouldComponentUpdate`, so that wrapped component doesn't rerender if `props` aren't changed. Since react-router use context to pass route changes, the wrapped component doesn't rerender when routes change. But it seems they are going to [remove `shouldComponentUpdate`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/pull/625) in 5.1 version of react-redux. Currently, as a workaround, I pass a prop coming from Router like `this.props.match.params` to connected child component even though I don't use it in inside. But it will make rerendering the component each time when routes change.

Comment: Can you write me a working usage example of PrivateRoute or changes need to be done on PrivateRoute itself

Comment: I can't think of any way to make PrivateRoute work as you expected in your 1 usage. My suggestion is that just go with usage 3 if it works for you until they fix this issue. Or you can pass `params` to PrivateRoute like this. `<PrivateRoute path="/member" component={MemberPage} params={this.props.match.params}/>`

Comment: also as one more workaround i use **forceUpdate()** right after the change history

Comment: **update:** i found out that parent components using redux must also be connected to *withRouter* therefrom there is no need use *forceUpdate()*