# React router 4 does not update view on link, but does on refresh

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using the following simple nav code

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path='/dashboard/accounts' component={AccountPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>

<NavLink exact to={'/dashboard'}
         disabled={this.props.item.disabled}
         activeClassName='active'>

<NavLink exact to={'/dashboard/accounts'}
         disabled={this.props.item.disabled}
         activeClassName='active'>
```

The URL changes but the view does not. It does however change when I refresh the page or manually go to that URL.

Comment: is your component react-redux connected component?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: Then I think probably you have the same problem which I have described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892050/react-router-4-x-privateroute-not-working-after-connecting-to-redux/43892528#answer-43892528

Answer (score 55):

You can also use the:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And then on your export default, you do like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Layout));
```

Because when you have an export connect, you need to tell that that component will be using the router.

Comment: We can use redux then how can we apply this method?

Comment: I have same proble of view not udpate but we have not used the redux then what was the issue for that or how can we apply your solution in our code?

Comment: I ran into the same issue recently, without using redux, looking for solution also

Answer (score 31):

This is because `react-redux` `connect` method implements `shouldComponentUpdate` which will cause component **not** to render when props didn't change. And this is conflicting now with react-router 4.

To avoid it you can pass `{pure: false}` to `connect` as described in [react-redux troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux).

Another way is to use `withRouter` HOC or pass `location` prop like [described in DOCS](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking).

Answer (score 5):

I had my Navlinks in a stateless-component (or dumb component) and a container to control the collapse-state of my navbar.

after switching the navbar-container from `PureComponent` to `Component`it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making sure that your router tags wrap the entire chunk of code?

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path='/dashboard/accounts' component={AccountPage} />
  </Switch>

  <NavLink exact to={'/dashboard'}
         disabled={this.props.item.disabled}
         activeClassName='active'>

  <NavLink exact to={'/dashboard/accounts'}
         disabled={this.props.item.disabled}
         activeClassName='active'>
</Router>
```

It looks odd, but including links into the `<Router>` propagates your path change to router components when you click the link and actually renders the component you are routing to. Just fixed a very similar problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem. I resolve it by add attribute key to component Switch with value is a location pathname and location search.

Comment: That worked for me! Now it works when I change manually the url. Example:

`<Switch key={loc.pathname + "@" + loc.hash + "@" + loc.search.toString()}>`

loc comes from useLocation(). Remember to call it in a child component of Router