# React router v4 not working with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-component

Developing a React application using React router v4. All worked well until I introduced Redux in my app. Since then on click of links to change route the browser url changes but the component corresponding to the route is not getting loaded. It works well if I comment out Redux code. What could be causing this? Here is my code for routing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LeftSubDefault from './../components/left-sub-default.component';
import LeftSubOne from './../components/left-sub-one.component';
import LeftSubTwo from './../components/left-sub-two.component';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { goToLeftDefault, goToLeftOne, goToLeftTwo } from "./../actions/leftRouteActions.js";

class LeftComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-6">
          <p>
            Current sub route: {this.props.currentRoute}
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={this.props.goToDefault}><Link to={'/'}>Go To Default</Link></li>
            <li onClick={this.props.goToSub1}><Link to={'/left-sub1'}>Go To One</Link></li>
            <li onClick={this.props.goToSub2}><Link to={'/left-sub2'}>Go To Two</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={LeftSubDefault} />
            <Route exact path='/left-sub1' component={LeftSubOne} />
            <Route exact path='/left-sub2' component={LeftSubTwo} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
    currentRoute: store.routes.currentRoute
  };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    goToDefault: () => {
      dispatch(goToLeftDefault())
    },
    goToSub1: () => {
      dispatch(goToLeftOne())
    },
    goToSub2: () => {
      dispatch(goToLeftTwo())
    }
  };
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LeftComponent));
```

PS: I get no error in console. The code runs clean just components don't load. Here is a similar thread on github: [4671](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671). I have seen lot of threads on various sites but none has the solution for this issue.

Comment: See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895805/react-router-4-does-not-update-view-on-link-but-does-on-refresh#answer-45036930), Exactly can help you.

Comment: [A Redux binding for React Router v4](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Hah, now I'm making a project with react-router and redux too =).

Look at the official documentation about redux integration https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration.

I think the main point is order of `withRouter` and `connect` Hocs.

> The problem is that Redux implements shouldComponentUpdate and there’s no indication that anything has changed if it isn’t receiving props from the router. This is straightforward to fix. Find where you connect your component and wrap it in withRouter.

From the official docs.

UPD

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Home extends React.Component {...}

export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToPropsFunc)(Home)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using react-router-dom v4.1.1. It is working for me. Here is my Demo

```
import React from 'react';

import Reducer1 from 'yourReducer1';
import Reducer2 from 'yourReducer2';


import {
    Route,
    Switch as RouterSwitch
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App =()=> (
<RouterSwitch>
    <Route path="/link1" exact component={Reducer1}/>
    <Route path="/link2" exact component={Reducer2}/>     
</RouterSwitch>
);

export default App;
```

Hope it is helpful for you ^^

Comment: what should i do to upgrade to 4.1.1? Any syntax changes in this version?

Comment: just try: "npm update all". I have not used this :D. Hier ist Link [Update npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-update-all)

Comment: Could yuu share your connect syntax please. That is where the issue lies. Please see my question updated.

Comment: Here is my index^^


    ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();'

Comment: withRouter worked, thanks much!  I was previously doing it in Leftcomponent where routing did not work. However I had to do it where the parent component was imported. LeftComponent was used in app.js so in app.js I had to use withRouter in app.js and not in LeftComponent js.

Comment: okay :)). Congratulations to find out :P. Can you give  me one vote :)). I have only 2 points to free comment :P