# React Router is redirecting to Login page but not rendering Login component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am doing a very basic authentication workflow by using React Router v4 as follows:

```
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (  
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    sessionStorage.getItem('jwt') ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { from: props.location }
      }} />
    )
  )}/>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
          <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={App}  />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

The flow works perfectly and when there is no 'jwt' the application is redirected to /login. However, strangely enough it is not getting rendered (i.e. blank page) until I press refresh from the browser.

Not sure how to debug and/or what could possible be the issue as this is a similar approach to most examples found online.

Comment: Is the `LoginPage` component mounting? (Stick a breakpoint, or log message in the `componentDidMount()` method)

Comment: Isn't Router responsible for mounting it?

Comment: do you use react-redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you use react-redux and it's a common issue. (If not I will delete answer)

use `{pure: false}` in react-redux `connect` or use `withRouter` HOC.

[React router 4 does not update view on link, but does on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895805/react-router-4-does-not-update-view-on-link-but-does-on-refresh)

Comment: Yes indeed that is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: But can we know which option did exactly help ya?

Answer (score 0):

I came here with same issue. My flow involved a modal popup in the product details page, clicking on **OK** button will do some task and take the user back to product listing page. Tried `{pure: false}`, and `withConnect(connect...`. Tried couple of other things as well. Nothing worked. Then the simplest thing worked. I opened the modal with `this.setState({showConfirmationModal: true});` So in the successHandler, in the `.then` of the `axios.get`, I closed it with `this.setState({showConfirmationModal: false});` and then used state property to render the <`Redirect` in `render()`. It worked !!. Hope this helps.