# Reactstrap or React-router v4's is not redirecting for partial address link change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router-v4, reactstrap

In my Header,

```
<NavItem>
   <NavLink tag={Link} to="/template/editor">New Template</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

In my Router page

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <Header />
    <section className="page-content">
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/template/editor/:id?" component={Authenticate(EditorPage)} />
    </section>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If I'm on my HomePage (/) and click on the New Template Link (/template/editor), it will redirect me to the New Template page. However, if I'm on (/template/editor/3), and click on the New Template Link (/template/editor), the address bar updates but the page isn't routed. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out what.

Comment: do you use react-redux and `connect` maybe?

Comment: @Tomasz yes, why?

Comment: maybe it's related to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895805/react-router-4-does-not-update-view-on-link-but-does-on-refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem but I believe that what you tried to do is:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <Header />
    <section className="page-content">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/template/editor/:id?" component={Authenticate(EditorPage)} />
      </Switch>
    </section>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

(Notice I used `Switch` from `react-router-dom` package)

also, you said you are using `react-redux` there is a known issue with a view not updating. [Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895805/react-router-4-does-not-update-view-on-link-but-does-on-refresh).

Comment: It looks like my problem. I fixed switch. However, I am hesitant about using pure: false due to performance. Is there a "right way" I should design the app so I don't have this issue? Is the withRouter option the better way?

Comment: @SILENT Yes, this is a bit "hacky". The `connect` compares props and if nothing has changed it doesn't re-render (even though app location has changed). You need to instruct `connect` to always re-render with `{ pure: false }` or... you can alternatively use `withRouter` (like explained in question I linked) to pass react-router props which change when location change.

Comment: I now have navigation requests run through my redux. This allowed me to escape the hacky method.