# React Router Link is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

React router Link doesn't seem to work for my app. It seems I am missing like basic doesn't work. My Link component updates the URL to be /products/singleproduct but my page just breaks....
Could anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

**App.js**

```html
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Body from './Body';
import Main from './Main';
require('../../scss/style.scss');

const App = () => (
    <div>
     <Header />
     <Main />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ServicePage from './ServicePage';
import ProductPage from './ProductPage';
import SingleProductPage from './SingleProductPage';
import Body from './Body';

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
          <Route path='/services' component={ServicePage} />
          <Route path='/products' component={ProductPage}>
            <Route path="/products/singleproduct" component={SingleProductPage} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

**ProductPage.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
require('../../scss/style.scss');

export default class ProductPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product-page">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="section-header-line"></div>
        <Link to="/products/singleProduct">
          Single Product
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know your situation exactly but here's a few things...

**One.** If you're using `[react-router-dom][1]`, you need to wrap your switch with a `BrowserRouter` by importing it like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then adding it around your switch like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Two.**
`react-router` & `react-router-dom` are 2 separate things. Make sure your imports are consistent. Change ProductPage.js ln.2 to:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

(right now, it's `import { Link } from 'react-router';`)

**Three.**
Play around with your nested routes. Order matters when it comes to routes. Without `exact`, it takes your URL and tries to match it with the first one on the list. If you have a more generic route like `/products` before `/products/somethingspecific` the router will route you when it hits the first one and never get to the more specific route *Try something like this:*

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
    <Route path='/services' component={ServicePage} />
    <Route path='/products/singleproduct' component={SingleProductPage} />
    <Route exact path='/products' component={ProductPage} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Good luck~!

Note: Not quite sure what "my page just breaks" means. Are you seeing any errors in your browser or console? If you could share more specifics, I think the SO community can help ya even more.

Comment: I have the issue, and it's none of the things you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try wrapping the `Switch` with a `Router` component:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
    <Route path='/services' component={ServicePage} />
    <Route path='/products' component={ProductPage} />
    <Route path="/products/singleproduct" component={SingleProductPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation where my Router Links were not working, and it ended up being the use of a `<StyleRoot>` within my App.js which caused the problem. After removing the `<StyleRoot>`...`</StyleRoot>` tags from App.js, I added them to a **specific** **component** which **truly needed it**. After this, my Router Links worked properly. Double check if any CSS Styling utilities such as `<StyleRoot>` (from Radium) are affecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are using react-redux so I bet this happens because connected components are not notified that props had changed and react doesn't re-render.

[Take a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565602/4443323)

as well as

[react-redux troubleshooting section.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux)

So basically try to use `{ pure: false }` on components where you use `connect(...` or use `withRouter` on them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be sure all of your components are in 
includes Header or layout components

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Link to="/somewhere" />  
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BrowserRouter
`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom"; <Router> <Link to={`/rooms/${id}`}> <div className='sidebarChat'> <Avatar src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg`}/>

### {name}

Last message....

`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32642254)