# Trying to get a redirect working with push using ConnectedRouter, my redux mapStateToProps is giving an error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

My application is not able to redirect using:

```
dispatch(push("/welcome"));
```

I tried to follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples/BasicExample.js) but using a ConnectedRouter.

The redirect seems to work as the URL changes now, but only the URL location changes and the view does not re-render and doesn't display the html for the /welcome page.

https://7wm1z5q666.codesandbox.io/welcome)

I created a live running example of my scenario, hoping someone can help me make sure I have all the pieces in place.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7wm1z5q666

Comment: Where're u getting this error? Is it in sign in page?

Comment: When I click on the 'sign in' button, it seems to redirect /welcome but the   component doesnt' actually render.  If I go directly to /welcome I get the error I posted.

Comment: Avoid using refs as it is useful when you need to find the DOM markup rendered by a component (for instance, to position it absolutely). You can use onChange

Comment: Where do you get this error specifically? `email of undefined`

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk I updated the question, that doesn't happen any longer.

Comment: In your demo I can see the page being redirected to /welcome and the html content rendered

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I implemented one of the answers below, just waiting until I am allowed to select the correct anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565602/4443323) view doesn't get updated when you change your route. And it is also described in `react-redux` [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux).

> If your views depend on global state or React “context”, you might
>   find that views decorated with connect() will fail to update.
>
> This is because connect() implements shouldComponentUpdate by default,
>   assuming that your component will produce the same results given the
>   same props and state. This is a similar concept to React’s
>   PureRenderMixin.

So the problem is within your `ConnectedSwitch` which will work if you change it to:

```
const ConnectedSwitch = connect(
  state => ({
    location: state.location
  }),
  null,
  null,
  { pure: false }
)(Switch);
```

or

```
const ConnectedSwitch = withRouter(
  connect(state => ({
    location: state.location
  }))(Switch)
);
```

It seems to me that `state.location` even though is coming from redux is being mutated not updated. That's why `shouldComponentUpdate` implemented by `connect` returns false.

Unfortunately, I don't get:

> Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

so I don't know how to help you with that.

Comment: how can I figure out which component is being called but not re-rendered?  In a more complicated reactjs app is there a way to debug this?  Will my components shouldComponentUpdate be overriden?

Comment: @Blankman You need to look for implementations of [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). If a component receives new props react will always re-render... unless shouldComponentUpdate returns false (by default always true). `connect` does shallow equal to received props and if they didn't change it will return false in this hook. This is why immutability is so important to always get a fresh view.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect code is fine.

Looks like you have problem here:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  email: state.users.email,
});
```

With an actual string, the page will correctly redirect and render.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  email: 'abcd@efg.com',
});
```

`state.users` is undefined, and it's because for some reason your `state` here is not pointing to the redux store, but `react-router`. I would look into your redux and router setup in `Root.js`.

Comment: How did you figure out the store pointing to the react-router? devtools or?

Comment: I added another mapStateToProps `aaa: state` and tried printing it