# ReactJS: Component not loaded even after URL changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

After spending time with `withRouter` and `connect` methods, I'm still unable to figure out why my view isn't updating with change in URL.

When I navigate from **"/"** to **"/about"**, page doesn't update, though works fine on reloading.

From React DevTools, I can see that my `props.location` doesn't change even after redirection. So my guess is that I have messed up the implementation of Redux somewhere.

**App.js**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Main from "./Main";

const actionCreators = {};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    const actions = bindActionCreators(actionCreators);

    return { ...actions, dispatch };
}

const App = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar.component";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer.component";

const Main = props => (
    <div>
        <Navbar currentState="Home" />
        {React.cloneElement(props.children, props)}
        <Footer />
    </div>
);

export default Main;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import store, { history } from "./store";

import App from "./App";
import Home from "./containers/home/home.component";
import AboutPage from "./containers/aboutPage/aboutPage.component";

const MOUNT_POINT = document.getElementById("root");

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
                </Switch>
            </App>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

render(
    router,
    MOUNT_POINT,
);
```

Though I am getting the following diff in Redux state (as below), but same is not being reflected in React State.

```
{
    "type": "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE",
    "payload": {
        "pathname": "/about",
        "search": ","
        hash ":",
        "key": "wk0oya"
    }
}
```

I believe I have somewhere messed up linking `redux` with `react-router`. Had tried the withRouter solution credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45036930/2302156.

I also tried passing options to `connect` method from `react-redux` [as per following API Guide](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md):

> [pure] (Boolean): If true, connect() will avoid re-renders and calls
>   to mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, and mergeProps if the relevant
>   state/props objects remain equal based on their respective equality
>   checks. Assumes that the wrapped component is a “pure” component and
>   does not rely on any input or state other than its props and the
>   selected Redux store’s state. Default value: true

My list of package dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Anyone who can help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not working because of wrong dependency included.

Changes in **index.js**,

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import store from "./store";

import App from "./App";
import Home from "./containers/home/home.component";
import AboutPage from "./containers/aboutPage/aboutPage.component";

const MOUNT_POINT = document.getElementById("root");

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
                </Switch>
            </App>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

render(
    router,
    MOUNT_POINT,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in `Main.js` you should use `{this.props.children}` instead of `{React.cloneElement(props.children, props)}`. `React.cloneElement` works properly if your child is a single React element and your `Main.js` looks more like layout (wrapper) for page content.

```js
import React from "react";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar.component";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer.component";

const Main = ({ children }) => (
    <div>
        <Navbar currentState="Home" />
        {children}
        <Footer />
    </div>
);

export default Main;
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried that but of no help. Also, please wrap `({ children })` with a pair of braces :)

Comment: Oh right, thanks!
Hmm, could you provide `codesandbox` version to debug it easier?

Comment: @ShreeshKatyayan well I looked into it a bit more and I think you've got bad structure inside the router. Inside `index.js` you could have structure like this imo. Then you shouldn't need to use `withRouter()`. As far as I checked `withRouter` is messing your state.

Could you try something like this? You shouldn't need here App component at all.
https://jsfiddle.net/s56p4n3o

Comment: I'm in transit currently. Will try out and get back within a couple of hours max. Thanks for all the effort mate!

Comment: Sure, tag me when you've checked it -> https://jsfiddle.net/s56p4n3o/2/ (fixed header and footer issue)