# React router v4 with redux protected routes and auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using react router v4 with redux and i want to make use of private and protected route to redirect if user is not logged in.

i have this Routes component:

```
class Routes extends Component {

render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    // so checks against isAuthenticated can pass
    if (auth.isAuthenticated !== undefined) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact component={() => <Home />} />
                <PublicRoute
                    authed={() => auth.isAuthenticated}
                    path="/login"
                    component={(routerProps) => <Login {...routerProps} />}
                />
                <PublicRoute
                    authed={() => auth.isAuthenticated}
                    path="/register"
                    component={(routerProps) => <Register {...routerProps} />}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                    authed={() => auth.isAuthenticated}
                    path="/dashboard"
                    component={Dashboard}
                />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return <div></div>
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes));
```

it is implemented like this:

```
class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(checkAuth());
}

render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Theme>
                    <Routes />
                </Theme>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the PrivateRoute:

```
export function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
const isAuthenticated = authed();
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated === true ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/login",
                        state: { from: props.location }
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
  );
}
```

What is the best way to pass that `auth` prop, is it ok if i connect the Routes component and pass the `auth` from there, or should i be passed from somewhere else, maybe connect each component that needs it and read from there? Also how would this approach play with nested routes, like `/dashboard/settings`? Thanks

Comment: if the parent doesn't need to know how `PrivateRoute` works, you could just connect the `PrivateRoute` directly.

Comment: @RobertFarley Yes, i will try that, thanks!

Comment: @RobertFarley but if you connect a lot of PrivateRoute you would have performance issues ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is ok to use this type of private route in react, but you should check two moments:

1. I should check, that you do not have `exact` attribute, so all your routes like `/dashboard/panel1`,  `/dashboard/panel2` will be private to

   auth.isAuthenticated}
     path="/dashboard"
     component={Dashboard}
   />
2. You will have some problem with connect. There is a simple fix for that:

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
     pure: false,
   })(PrivateRoute);

more information here: 
[React router private routes / redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520498/react-router-private-routes-redirect-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that thing with exact, will try it.

Comment: sorry i deleted your answer, still new here